# Calling a dynamic function after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

```
 $('a.action').on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s/);
  var action = classes[classes.length -1];
  var url = "/api/" + action + "/" + $(this).attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
  }).done(function(data){
    //function-name(data);
  });   
});
```

The above code is attached to a click event, on a link like this:

```
<a class="action setsize" href="1">Go</a>
```

I already set the URL to call via ajax, using the class names, but I also want to run a function after its been called *done()*, to update my html. I want this function to have the samne name as the ajax call, so it needs to take its name from the 'action' var.

How would I achieve this? The dynamic function syntax is new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
classes[index].callback = function(data){
    // do something
}
...

var action = classes[classes.length -1];
var url = "/api/" + action + "/" + $(this).attr('href');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
}).done(function(data){
    action.callback(data);
});
```

every element in classes array will have a method named callback which is invoked after ajax done.

Comment: thanks. I'm slightly unclear how to implement this. By any chance could you post a pastebin for an example class of set-size? I fail to see how I could use class-specific functions. Thanks!